# Sony Vaio laptop boots automatically on opening the lid

Tags: windows-8, boot, laptop, sony-vaio

I have a sony vaio ESeries laptop with Windows 8. I have currently disabled the hybrid mode provided in Windows 8. The problem is, even though I shutdown my laptop, as soon as I open the lid of my laptop again it boots automatically and launches IE once the boot process is finished. In IE it tries to open up whatever the default page the browser is set too.

Please tell me how I can stop this from happening?

PS - I have scanned the system with Malware Bytes, Avast, SpyBot and Windows Defender already, so it doesn't look to me like a virus related issue.

Comment: Check your settings in `Vaio Control Center` > `Power Management` > `Lid Action Settings`

Answer (score 1):

To change the action when you open the lid, change the settings in Lid Action Settings under Power Management on VAIO Control Center.

and
unselect all shutdown setting

Answer (score 0):

Source [Using Sleep Mode](http://docs.esupport.sony.com/pc/SVS1311_13A1_1511_series/EN/contents/03/03/06/06.html)

> You can restore your VAIO computer from Sleep mode to Normal mode by opening the LCD screen lid.
>
> **To change the action when you open the lid, change the settings in Lid Action Settings under Power Management on VAIO Control Center.**

Comment: I tried this solution. It didn't work though. I had set the Lid Open Action to Do Nothing but it didn't work out. Can you tell me if there is any other alternate to this?